# C memory address and values

Tags: c

I have a problem I can't seem to figure it out. I hope someone could be able to throughly explain it to me. I get that its very elementary..

Problem is following:

How do the following variables go into consecutive memory addresses and their value?

```
int8_t a = 0x65;
char b = 'k';
uint16_t c = 22222;
```

for example,

```
int8_t esim = 9;
```

would be stored as

```
0000:00001001
```

Anyone?

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The binary format in memory of each variable? The address alignment of them? For each variable separately or all together? Some clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: *How do the following variables go into consecutive memory addresses...?* Why do you think they do?

Comment: It's processor specific.  Why don't you print the address of these variables and see for yourself what your processor does. `printf("%p: %d\n", &a, a);`

Comment: the problem is how would those three variables would be presented as the example is.

Comment: If Antti's answer is too long, just go with "implementation defined"

Comment: Notice that the mere *presence* of `&` there forces the variable to be stored in memory and can therefore [cause an observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)) ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a problem I can't seem to figure it out. I hope someone could be able to throughly explain it to me. I get that its very elementary.

And here you go wrong. It *is* very elementary but not quite as you think it to be

- Distinct variables need not be stored in consecutive locations in memory. (Or as the last bullet says, not be stored in memory at all)
- The storage of individual bytes within a multibyte value is *implementation-defined* - check your compiler manuals. Most personal computing processors nowadays use little-endian 2's complement for integers, however.
- Even if they *were* organized by the compiler to appear in memory in exactly the same order as they are declared, each datatype can require an implementation-specific alignment and can therefore start only at an address that is multiple of this alignment
- And finally, there need not be any variables or memory allocations whatsoever, the compiler just needs to generate a program that behaves [*as if*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) there were such variables.

---

We can *certainly* say something about your program however. If the excerpt

```
#include <stdint.h>

int8_t a = 0x65;
char b = 'k';
uint16_t c = 22222;
```

compiles *and* the variables are placed in memory, then

- `a` will be 8 bits with value `0b01100101`
- `c` will be 16 bits and stored in memory as *2* bytes - `0b11001110` and `0b01010110` at increasing memory addresses (little-endian, usual), or the same 2 bytes reversed: `0b01010110` and `0b11001110` (big-endian).
- As for `b`, *if* the *execution character set* is ASCII-compatible, as `int8_t` exists, then `char` must also be 8 bits wide, then its value will be stored as `0b01101011` (i.e. 107, the ASCII code of `k`).

Additionally, most often the alignment requirement of an `uint16_t` object is 2; if that is the case, it must start at an even address.

This deduction is only possible because the `int8_t` and `uint16_t` *must not have padding bits*, hence from having them we can deduce that the width of the smallest addressable unit (`char`) must be 8 bits too. And `uint16_t` has only 2 bytes, hence it can only have two choices for endianness.

---

It is easy to test how GCC organizes *global variables*. Consider the module having the source code

```
#include <stdint.h>
int8_t a = 0x65;
char b = 'k';
uint16_t c = 22222;
```

we can compile it to an object file:

```
% gcc -c layouttest.c -o layouttest.o
```

and then use `nm` to list the symbols and their addresses:

```
% nm layouttest.o            
0000000000000000 D a
0000000000000001 D b
0000000000000002 D c
```

It seems to be as Jabberwocky's answer expects. If we now compile with `-O3`, the results can be different:

```
% gcc -c layouttest.c -o layouttest.o -O3; nm layouttest.o
0000000000000003 D a
0000000000000002 D b
0000000000000000 D c
```

I.e. the variables were reorganized, with `c` at the bottom.

Comment: Great post Antti. This was very clearly represented. What about the memory addresses where the value is stored?

Comment: @teepa `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` beyond the alignment requirement of `b` they could be *absolutely anything*, besides the `NULL`, as `NULL` cannot point to any valid object, and they cannot overlap either.

Comment: @teepa you shouldn't assume anything either.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you should add that we can in many circumstances force the compiler do not optimize the variables  and configure the memory the way we want (for example uC programming). So it may be even more complicated

Answer (score 2):

Complement to Antti Haapala's answer:

While it is totally up to the compiler how and where to store variables, the memory layout of variables declared consecutively is often in the same order than the order of declaration especially in non optimized code.

So the variables declared like this:

```
int8_t a = 0x65;
char b = 'k';
uint16_t c = 22222;
```

*could* be stored like this:

```
Address  Content in binary
--------------------------
0000:    01010101  (0x64)
0001:    01101011  ('k' = 107, ASCII code of k)
0002:    11001110  (low bits of 22222)
0003:    01010110  (high bits of 22222)
```

where `Address` is the relative address with repsect to the memory address of variable `a`.

Once again: don't assume that this is the necessarily the case on your platform.

Comment: Note that depending on whether or not the variables were local (and stored on a stack) they might be in the opposite order

Comment: @TimRandall yes sure, that's why I wrote _could_ and _often_.